# Blank screen getting controller instance on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

With this code , I get a blank screen, and the debug stop but doesn't shows an error

```
 $instance = app('App\Http\Controllers\MyControllers\ConsumerController');
 $consumerSegmentList = $this->getSegmentList($instance);
```

The problem its when I try to get a controller instance with `app` function the route its correct but I don't know whats the problem, this code its ib `ParentController` which is the parent of `ConsumerController`

Comment: where are you doing this, in what context? what is `getSegmentList` doing with the controller instance?

Comment: the problem its on instance, when  app funcion is called the execution stops